# Designing form inputs that need approval by a second user

Tags: forms, input-fields

I have the following scenario - in my web application, a user can update a form. But before the updated form can go live, a second user approves or rejects each change. As a default, each change is rejected.

1. Some input fields are empty, and the second user has to fill in the data in order to approve it.
2. Then, for fields that have a value, the second user has to click on the appropriate icons (approve/reject).
3. Checkboxes and radio buttons are also approved or rejected.

Is this the right pattern for showing items that need this action?

[image]

Comment: are the 'x' and check icons the approve or reject icons? Also, one user A fills out the form, can they see the form as the second analyst goes through and approves or rejects fields at the input level? Also, can the analyst change the form inputs, or just give a approve or reject?

Answer (score 1):

If the primary interaction for the approver is to click a button to approve, make them larger so they are easy to click (assuming you currently want them to click the little icon). I think the red and green is too much and distracts from the contents.

Also consider keyboard navigation. Some users might prefer that as it can be a lot faster than using the mouse.

Align the approved / rejected indicators so that it's easily scannable on the page. For example by placing the icons to the left of all fields (textfield, checkbox etc).

If you post some screens of an actual layout, in the different phases, we can be more helpful. Interesting project :)

Answer (score 1):

Why is everything rejected by default? No error has been made. The default should be "not approved" which has no visual cue and a approved state in green.

Also there are 2 journey the one from the "user" and the "approver". The first one's job is to fill out the form, so he only sees the form and if it has been approved (e.g. a checkmark icon).

The second one's job is to approve. so there should be a focus on approval buttons.

Furthermore I would question if every checkbox or radio button has to be approved but rather the made choice in that segment. so there should be an approve button for that radio button group / that question.